# I installed an Android studio, but it doesn't work, 0xc000012f error message is displayed

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently using Windows 11, and I downloaded Android Studio Giraffe and installed it
It was not executed and an error message occurred

An image that has an error in c:\windows\SYSTEM32\VCRUNTIME140_1.dll or cannot be run by Windows. Try reinstalling the program using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or software vendor for assistance. Error status 0xc000012f

Failed to load JVM DLL C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\server\jvm.dll
If you already have a JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in
Computer >System Properties >System Settings >Environment Variables

Android Studio is not working
Please give us a lot of answers

I erased and reinstalled the Android studio
It didn't work
I updated Windows 11, erased it again, and downloaded it
It didn't work
I looked up the Internet There was an example of a visual studio
I don't need it
I want to get the Android studio up and running and I need that information

Comment: That error tells you to install JDK and set the JAVA_HOME variables, have you done that?

Comment: As for the VCRUNTIME just google for that exact version and reinstall it

Comment: Can https://download.oracle.com/java/20/latest/jdk-20_windows-x64_bin.msi (sha256) get this? If this is correct, I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to set up JAVA_HOME variables. What version of VCR UNTIME should I get?

Comment: I haven't solved it yet, but thank you for your answer

Comment: Have you tried to google your question? The JAVA_HOME instruction is very clear. As for the version, if you google that DLL name you'll see the exact version you need

Comment: I received the jdk from the Oracle homepage, and I set the JAVA HOME setting according to the https://mk28.tistory.com/273 method 
VCRUNTIME140_1.dll Error Resolved Thank you to the respondent who gave me a hint as an answer. It's been resolved.

Comment: Received jdk from Oracle homepage https://coding-factory.tistory.com/838 
I set up JAVA HOME according to the method and https://mk28.tistory.com/273 method 
VCRUNTIME140_1.dll Error Resolved Thank you to the respondent who gave me a hint as an answer. It's been resolved.